# How to get h1 and ul to stick on the same line

Tags: html, css

Good day once again.

I have a (seemingly) simple problem. I'm trying to display `<h1>` and a `<ul>` on the same line. I have used float, inline and many other ways but it doesn't seem to work. It is like the header doesn't want to play along with unordered list. All help appreciated.

The html code looks like this:

```
<div class="page">
   <div id="header">
            <h1>IRIS</h1>


            <ul id="menu">              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Forsíða", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Fréttir", "Index", "News")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Greinar", "Index", "Article")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Síðan Mín", "Index", "MySite")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Spurt & Svarað", "QA", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Upplýsingar", "Index", "Information")%></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And the css code I'm using looks like this:

```
.page
{
width: 70%;
margin-left: Auto;
margin-right: Auto;
}



body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;    
background: url('/Content/Image/background-gradient.png') repeat-x;
}


#header
{
background-color: Gray;
}

#header h1:
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
}

ul#menu
{
display:inline;
border:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
padding: 0 0 2px;
margin: 0;
text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li
{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting
{
padding: 10px 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a
{
padding: 5px 10px;
float:left;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
background-color: #e8eef4;
color: #034af3;
}

ul#menu li a:hover
{
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:active
{
background-color: #a6e2a6;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a
{
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
}

#main
{
border: solid black;
clear:both;    
width:75%;
padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**Ok so the answer to the problem has been found, thanks to Mathieu and everyone else.
This is what I used:**

```
#header h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:7px;
    display:inline;
}

ul#menu
{
    width:85%;
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

If anyone thinks of something better please post :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector for h1 was wrong :

```
h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}
```

And for ul and li, you dont need float

```
ul#menu
{
    display:inline;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

See fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Y6D6p/

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with mine but I they are still on two different lines (also forgot to add the <div id="header"> in the original post, fixed now)

Comment: @Siemsen remove the ":" after "#header h1:"

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. But now they are in the same line, but the H1 comes after the ul. Any ideas? (Thanks by the way)

Comment: I tried that but when I did that the background color for the #header disappeared. But I have found a solution to this, I floated the menu right and then set the width using percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Float both the `h1` and the `ul`.

You may be experiencing issues because `#header h1 ul:` does not match the `ul`. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to match on; if its supposed to be a style for the `ul`, then just do this `#header ul`. If its for the `h1`, then do `#header h1`.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect what has been said (and what I forgot), still having issues though. (Thanks for the tip though)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in FF4 and IE8 as well:

```
<h1 style="display: inline;">IRIS</h1>
       <ul id="menu" style="display: inline;">              
            <li style="display: inline;">aaa</li>
            <li style="display: inline;">bbbb</li>
            <li style="display: inline;">ccccccc</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Dude. Never do inline styles like that. Ever.

Comment: of course, I just wanted to demonstrate the styles that have to be set by means of css.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many ways to achieve that. i would do this like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1, ul { display: table-cell; }
            li {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>LIPSUM</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

or

```
        h1 { position: absolute; }
        ul { margin-left: 60px; }
```